# __init__.py not working as expected in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have the below module structure:

```
/home/Dir1/Dir2/Mod.py
```

Inside /home i have the script `Test.py` which I am executing and has the below code :

```
import Dir1.Dir2 
dummy()
```

Again the Directory: `Dir1` has an `__init__.py` file which has the below code:

```
print('dir1 init')
x = 1
```

The directory `Dir2` has the below `__init__.py` file having the following code:

```
from Mod import dummy
print('dir2 init')
y = 2
```

There is a final file `Mod.py` which is defined as follows:

```
print ("in Mod.py")
z = 3
def dummy():
    print ("Hello World")
```

Since `Test.py` is the entry point in my application this is the below error I get:

```
dir1 init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Dir1.Dir2
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\Desktop\Everything\Codes\Python\Dir1\Dir2\__init__.py"
, line 1, in <module>
    from Mod import dummy
ImportError: No module named 'Mod'
```

Why is the `__init__.py` file inside `Dir2` not able to find the file `Mod.py`?

Basically what I am trying to do here is make the function dummy inside `Mod.py` public without the user knowing that there is a module by that name.

Am I doing something silly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Test.py` to use `dummy` with the fully qualified name:

```
import Dir1.Dir2

Dir1.Dir2.dummy()
```

and your `Dir1/Dir2/.__init__.py` to use a relative import with a leading `.` in front of `Mod`:

```
from .Mod import dummy
print('dir2 init')
y = 2
```

to make it work:

```
python Test.py 
dir1 init
in Mod.py
dir2 init
Hello World
```

**Note**: Per convention all package (i.e. directory) and module (i.e. `py` file) names should be lower case.